# A Weird Modular Arithmetic Question

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, problem-solving

I saw this question somewhere and I was wondering if there's a nice closed form answer to it. It just seems like a troll question to me.

$2016^{2016} + 2018^{2016} (\bmod{2017}^{2016})$

I proceeded like this:
$(2017-1)^{2016} + (2017+1)^{2016} (\mod 2017^{2016})$

then I expanded it using the binomial theorem and noticed that some parts cancel with each other and from there I got stuck.

I'm kind of new to number theory so I will highly appreciate a detailed explanation. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? MSE isn't a windmill.

Comment: I tried using the binomial theorem and noticed that some parts cancel out and from there I got stuck. What's MSE btw?

Comment: MSE is Math Stack Exchange.

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Okay will edit it!

Comment: There's no need for copying an already existing answer...

Comment: I swear I did the same. I just forgot to mention it since I am new to MSE.

Comment: I think your suspicion that it's a troll question is correct.

Comment: This question is really helpful for the unfamiliar if it's mod 2017 . . . it's tedious otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite this expression as

$$2016^{2016}+2018^{2016}(\mod 2017^{2016})$$ $$\iff$$ $$(2017-1)^{2016} + (2017+1)^{2016} (\mod 2017^{2016}),$$ and then use the binomial theorem.

Comment: I tried doing that but I got stuck at some point. However, I noticed that some parts cancel out and from there I got stuck. Can you please elaborate more?